# Bigquery Rolling Count Distinct

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to have a rolling count for daily visitors

Example.

| date | visitor |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | A |
| 2022-02-01 | B |
| 2022-02-01 | C |
| 2022-02-02 | D |
| 2022-02-02 | E |
| 2022-02-03 | C |
| 2022-02-03 | F |

I want the output to be:

| date | count_visitor |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | 3 *(ABC)* |
| 2022-02-02 | 5 *(DE)* |
| 2022-02-03 | 6 *(CF)* |

I can't seem to find the query for this. Kindly need your help/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select date, daily_count, daily_visitors_list, 
  ( select count(distinct visitor)
    from unnest(split(rolled_visitors)) visitor
  ) rolled_count
from (
  select date, daily_count, daily_visitors_list, 
    string_agg(daily_visitors_list) over(order by unix_date(date)) rolled_visitors
  from (
    select date, count(distinct visitor) daily_count, 
      string_agg(distinct visitor) daily_visitors_list, 
    from your_table
    group by date
  )
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

If you have heavy amount of data - above approach might end up with resource related error  - in this case you can use below approach - it is using HyperLogLog++ functions

```
select date, daily_count, daily_visitors_list,
  ( select hll_count.merge(sketch)
    from t.rolling_visitors_sketches sketch 
  ) rolled_count
from (
  select date, daily_count, daily_visitors_list,
    array_agg(daily_visitors_sketch) over(order by unix_date(date)) rolling_visitors_sketches
  from (
    select date, count(distinct visitor) daily_count, 
      string_agg(distinct visitor) daily_visitors_list, 
      hll_count.init(visitor) daily_visitors_sketch
    from your_table
    group by date
  )
) t
```

> HLL++ functions are approximate aggregate functions. Approximate aggregation typically requires less memory than exact aggregation functions, like COUNT(DISTINCT), but also introduces statistical uncertainty. This makes HLL++ functions appropriate for large data streams for which linear memory usage is impractical, as well as for data that is already approximate.